# Подключение libpcap

Tags: c++, cmake, pcap, libpcap

Я не очень хорошо разбираюсь в CMake. Как подключить libpcap в проекте? Качаю архив с офф сайта tcpdump 
libpcap-1.9.1. В архиве в папке `cmake/modules` есть `FindPacket.cmake`. Как я понимаю, он и отвечает за подключение библиотеки, но не получается.
мой `CMakeLists.txt:`

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16)
project(somename)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)
include_directories(libpcap-1.9.1)
list(APPEND CMAKE_MODULE_PATH "${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/libpcap-1.9.1/cmake/Modules")
find_package(Packet REQUIRED)
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} main.cpp )
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${PACKET_LIBRARY})
```

В самом проекте

```
#include <pcap.h>
```

но при использовании любой функции из libpcap, вылетает ошибка

```
undefined reference to ...
```

Comment: А вы хоть скомпилировал библиотеку?

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch я думал она уже скомпилирована и надо только залинковать. А как тогда, собственно, ее правильно скомпилировать?

Comment: это было бы смешно если бы не было так грустно...

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch отличный ответ, сразу все понял.

Comment: во-первых это не ответ а комментарий, во-вторых: какой вопрос - такие и комментарии

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch совершенно адекватный вопрос. Человек, который никогда этим не занимался и не разбирается, качает архив и видит там кучу файлов, вместо привычных библиотек. Что делать дальше не понятно вообще. И вместо того, чтоб дать какой то ответ, совет что почитать чтоб разобраться, направить в правильное русло, нужно написать иронию, чтоб самоутвердиться. ну дело ваше.

Comment: ну слушайте: вы сами признаете что не разбираетесь даже в базовом программировании и хотите чтобы вам в чем то помогли и посоветовали. В вашем случае совет может быть только в одном: начинайте учить язык, разберитесь с процессом компиляции, узнайте что такое библиотеки и бинарником, ну а потом уже можно заниматься чем то более продвинутым. К тому же, если вы не заметили, я решил уже вашу проблему из вопроса, но вместо благодарности, вы тут заявляете, что я самоутверждаюсь за вас счёт...

Answer (score 0):

Если вам нужна библиотека для анализа файлов - проще использовать https://github.com/wkoroy/pcap_file_generator